# How to print this pattern in java

Tags: java

**if argument multiply 3 print "JU"

if argument multiply 5 print "MP"

if argument multiply 3 and 5 print "JUMP"**

**ex :**

```
> java myclass 16
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    1
    2
    JU
    4
    MP
    JU
    7
    8
    JU
    MP
    11
    JU
    13
    14
    JUMP
    16
```

Comment: Yet another variation on FizzBuzz...

Comment: 10 is not divisible by 3 and 5.

Comment: @mr.Lakmal Correct your out put....as 9MP11

Answer (score 3):

```
// for each number in the sequence 1..N execute the following
for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
  // print JU if divides by 3
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.print("JU");
  }
  // print MP if divides by 5
  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    System.out.print("MP");
  }
  // note that if it divides by 3 and by 5 (by 15 actually) 
  // it print JU and MP in a row and it becomes JUMP

  // if not dividable - print it itself
  if (i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0) {
    System.out.print(i);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: My guess would be unexplained code, the OP will learn nothing from copying and pasting this

Comment: @RichardTingle, that's possible. I added a couple of comments.

Comment: @RichardTingle but to be fair the code is so simple that I'm not sure how to follow the rule "explain what you do, now how" without duplicating programming statement in the comment.

Comment: It is a fair point, the fault is with the OP. If they'd bothered to explain what their difficulty actually was rather than just posting a spec then we might have something to go on

Answer (score 2):

This a variant of FizzBuzz and is a common challenge given to new programmers or in interviews. Why not have a look at the [Rosetta Code's Java section on FizzBuzz](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz#Java) to see a whole range of ways to do it. You'll obviously need to change Fizz for 'JU' and Buzz for 'MP'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public static void getNumber(int upperLimit){
    boolean status=true;
    int i=1;
     while (status) {
         if(i%3==0){
             System.out.println("JU");
         }else if(i%5==0){
        System.out.println("MP");
         }else if(i%5==0&&i%3==0){
        System.out.println("JUMP");
         }else {
        System.out.println(i);
         }
         if(i==upperLimit){
             status=false;
         }
         i++;
     }
}
```